# Mysql select just one row per day in interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql DB with multiple that contains data like this.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f084c

```
CREATE TABLE `datos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `temperatura` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `datos` (`id`, `fecha`, `temperatura`) VALUES
(1874, '2017-05-20 01:56:40', 20),
(1875, '2017-05-20 01:56:51', 20),
(1876, '2017-06-18 23:32:49', 17),
(1877, '2017-06-18 23:34:50', 17),
(1878, '2017-06-18 23:36:51', 17),
(1879, '2017-06-18 23:38:52', 17),
(1880, '2017-06-18 23:46:02', 16),
(1881, '2017-06-18 23:47:12', 17),
(1882, '2017-06-22 01:06:27', 21);
```

I want to select just one value of a day during a 30 day interval, to have a result like this

```
2017-06-22 01:06:27 21
2017-06-18 23:47:12 17
2017-05-20 01:56:51 20
```

I have selected the entire interval using

```
SELECT * FROM `datos` WHERE fecha >= '2017-06-22 01:06:27' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

But i have not managed to just select one value per day instead of all of them.
Would appreciate the help

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about GROUP BY. This is a common SQL operation, and any reference or tutorial on SQL will give you explanation and examples. For example, read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html and its sub-sections.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the 30 days. Perhaps the data set isn't very representative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the desired result you listed, it looks like you want maximum fecha for each day.

```
select date(fecha), max(fecha)
from datos
group by date(fecha)
```

This results in the following:

```
2017-06-22   2017-06-22 01:06:27
2017-06-18   2017-06-18 23:47:12
2017-05-20   2017-05-20 01:56:51
```

By treating the above query as a table and joining it back to the datos table you  can get the complete record: id, fecha, and temperatura which had the maximum fecha each day.

```
select d1.*
from datos d1,
(select date(fecha), max(fecha) as max_fecha
from datos
group by date(fecha) ) d2
where d1.fecha = d2.max_fecha
and d1.fecha >= '2017-06-22 01:06:27' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Resulting in the following:

```
1875   2017-05-20   2017-05-20 01:56:51   20
1881   2017-06-18   2017-06-18 23:47:12   17
1882   2017-06-22   2017-06-22 01:06:27   21
```

**Note** I initially solved in Oracle since I do not have access to a mysql database, but I believe I correctly altered the queries to work in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* 
from datos a 
  left outer join datos b 
  on substr(a.fecha,1,10) = substr(b.fecha,1,10) and a.id < b.id
where b.id is null
```

You can manipulate your conditions of matching to select whatever property of the rows you want to prioritize.